# Delayed playback of videos (Youtube, VLC)

Tags: pulseaudio, video

I'm using an Upnp renderer device for my default computer audio.
For this purpose I'm using https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna.

My problem is that in spite all my efforts, there is a huge 2s latency in audio. I.e. it takes 2s between my click on "Play" button and hear the first beat with my ears.

Renderer device is not configurable, it has some buffer which has to be filled up first, then it will start playing it back.

So my obvious question here is: anyhow is it possible to delay the playback of videos (generally, system-wide), to fake a 2s silent audio, then it can actually start the video and its audio to make my video and audio synced better?

Comment: are you only wishing to have the audio of a video play as opposed to play the video in order to listen to the audo?

Comment: I'd like to watch a YT video on my PC with it's audio in sync on the Upnp renderer. But now, when I start a video, it starts immediately, and it's audio is being buffered by the renderer, and only starts playing it after 2seconds (or so). So video is 2s forward compared to its audio. I wish to watch it in sync.

Comment: OK there's a terminal option to extract the sound from a (eg) youtube video which I use which is why I mentioned it.